# php array. unable to find value from the key

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

please help me figure out the error to find the value by key. As the value is printed when using a string but not a variable with the same value. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
print_r($ESSID_data);
print_r($ESSID_data['criticalboot']);
print_r($myssid);
print_r($ESSID_data[$myssid]);
```

output:

```
Array ( [criticalboot] => Array ( [0] => CCMP [1] => PSK ) ) 
Array ( [0] => CCMP [1] => PSK ) 
criticalboot 
Undefined index: criticalboot
```

Comment: Instead of `print_r` use `var_dump` and check again.

Comment: How is `$myssid` declared? Maybe it contains a space.

Comment: I tested this by declaring `$ESSID_data = array("criticalboot" => array("CCMP", "PSK"));` and `$myssid = "criticalboot";` and it works just fine.

Comment: Trailing whitespace...? Non-printing characters...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do `trim()` first before feeding it into the index. Like:

```
$myssid = trim($myssid);
print_r($ESSID_data[$myssid]);
```